# PHP execute Python

Tags: php, python, execute

I am trying to make at php page what execute a python program. 
The python program writes some html code, that I can use in my php page. 
When I execute the python program from a terminal, is all work fine.

But then I execute the python program from php nothing happen.
    If I use `exec("python program.py",$output)` the `$output == "array ( )"`

```
BUT if I remove the line `f = open('/var/www/data.php', w)`  
the `$output == " array ( 0 => 'start program', 1 => 'open error' ) "`
```

cut of php code:

```
 output = null;
 exec("python /var/www/webwrite.py", $output);
 echo var_export($output, TRUE);
```

cut of python code:

```
print "start program"

f =  open('/var/www/data.php', 'w')
if f <> 0:
    print "open file"
    f.write('<div class=divdata><pclass="data">Data</p><div id="webdata">')
    fstr = '%3.1f'%data
    f.write(fstr)
    f.write('</div></div>')
    f.close()
else:
   print "open error" here
```

How can I use `open(filename, w)` in python executed from php ?
And why can't I use open command then exec from php.
Is where an alternative to "open"

Comment: Comparing `f <> 0` is pointless.  If `open` fails, it will raise an *exception*, causing your script to be terminated.  Otherwise the comparison will always be True (a file object is different from the number 0).

Answer (score 0):

Generally in these cases, you likely either have a PATH or permissions problem.

Try to chown the py script to the same owner as that the web server is running as, for example (assuming web server is running as single user):

```
chown apache:apache your.py
```

Any files it opens or write to would also need to be owned by the same user.  Then you may need to increase permissions:

```
chmod 775 your.py
```

If that doesn't work, put in the full path to your python script.  You can get this with:

```
which python
```

Don't hard code these full paths into PHP the code though, put it in a config file.

Comment: I get this message <code> chown: invalid user: `apache:apache'
</code>

Comment: That means the php server is running as a different user.  You may see it from `top` (assuming you are using linux), or  under the /etc/httpd/ or /etc/apache config dir (assuming you are using apache).